# Differentiating between Json.Linq.JValue and Json.Linq.JObject

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to parse a JSON string, the issue is the API would return an empty string which is in the form on a Linq.JValue datatype and the other time it would return a child with type Linq.JObject. I want to handle both the responses in a dynamic manner, I am struggling to differentiate these two.

Example responses -

```
"ITEMIZEDCHARGES": {
      "ITEM": [
        {
          "@TYPE": "CHARGE",
          "@FOR": "FREIGHT",
          "@AMOUNT": "627.28",
          "@DESCRIPTION": "400 LB CL50, 3 PLT @ 48 x 48 x 48 IN"
        },
        {
          "@TYPE": "CHARGE",
          "@FOR": "FSC",
          "@AMOUNT": "161.84",
          "@DESCRIPTION": "/ FUEL SURCHARGE",
          "@RATE": "25.8%"
        }
      ]
    },
    

   Or 

"ITEMIZEDCHARGES" : ""
```

IMG : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vYL9.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the type of the value for ITEMIZEDCHARGES then go according to what you expect by using `GetType()` on its value and comparing it with either `typeof(JObject)` or `typeof(JValue)`.

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("@TYPE")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@FOR")]
    public string For { get; set; }
    // ....
}

var jObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

List<Item> yourObject = null;
if (jObj["ITEMIZEDCHARGES"].GetType().Equals(typeof(JObject)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Its a JObject");
    yourObject = jObj["ITEMIZEDCHARGES"]["ITEM"].ToObject<List<Item>>();
}

else if (jObj["ITEMIZEDCHARGES"].GetType().Equals(typeof(JValue)))
    Console.WriteLine("Its a String value");
```

You will need to do other checks to make sure the keys exist in your object.